# Python basic concept I am a MATH idiot SOS

Tags: python

As I know index in Python is always 1 less than the position. I can understand `range(5)` outputs `0,1,2,3,4` because it always starts at 0. But then why does `range(5,10)` output `5,6,7,8,9` instead of starting at `4`?

Comment: Because `range(x,y)` covers [x, y). It just does.

Comment: `help(range)` would have told you `range(start, stop[, step])` -- you are telling it to start at `5`. Simple as that.

Comment: In `range(x,y)`, `x` is the first number to produce, and `y` is the first number to not produce.  That is, it's `x` to `y-1`.   I suggest reading some documentation.

Comment: Why is this question marked with the [tag:java] tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `range()` with one argument, it is assumed to be the *end* of the range, and the beginning defaults to 0.

When you call range with two arguments, they are used as the beginning and the end.

`range()` stops counting *before* the end value.